# Running a cucumber feature multiple times

Tags: ruby, rake, cucumber

I'm trying to run a cucumber feature multiple times (i.e 500 times). Is there a way of doing this than me having to type in the same command everytime? I'm guessing this can be done using Rake? I'm not an expert in using rake or cucumber.

Will appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: How is this related to watir?

Comment: I can't believe I'm the first to say it, but: don't do this.

Comment: Why not do this? If you are testing, and a test is flaky, it may be useful to run it 5 times to see how many times it fails and if it fails in the same place every time.

Answer (score 9):

```
ruby -e '500.times { `cucumber` }'
```

Comment: I'm sure you can just do this in a bash script as well, but I know ruby better than bash.

Comment: `for x in {1..500}; do cucumber; done` should do the trick unless you are running an older version of Bash. It's actually easier, shorter, and faster in Ruby, though!

Comment: When I run this on windows i get no output.  Running cucumber at the prompt only one time or with -f progress works and displays output as expected.  Edited: if I add puts before 'cucumber' it displays output.

Answer (score 6):

Within your rake file:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'cucumber'
require 'cucumber/rake/task'

cuke_task = Cucumber::Rake::Task.new(:features) do |t|
  t.cucumber_opts = "features --format pretty"
end

task :feature, :name, :times do |task,args|
  puts "Executing feature: #{args[:name]} #{args[:times]} times"
  cuke_task.cucumber_opts = "features/#{args[:name]}"
  args[:times].to_i.times { Rake::Task[:features].execute }
end
```

First I create a default cucumber task that would execute all my features and format them pretty for me.

After that I define a rake task, named `feature` that would accept two parameters `name` of the feature and `times` of execution.

I then augment the cuke task to use the feature `name` that I specified and then execute the Rake task the number of times specified.

```
$ rake feature['login.feature',500]
```

Comment: Upvoted. When I implemented this if a test failed the program would exit so you may have to wrap the execute line in a try catch block

Answer (score 3):

Tag your feature with something like: @AndIwillwalk500miles

```
@AndIwillwalk500miles
Feature: Walk A Mile
  'That I can walk a mile in another man's shoes.'

  Scenario: That I can walk a Mile in loafers
    Given I am wearing loafers
    And I start at point A
    When I walk a mile
    Then I am at point B
```

Create a ruby file in your `features/support/` folder.  Convention seems to be `env.rb` or `hooks.rb`, but it doesn't matter what you call it as long as it's in that folder.  I call mine `env.rb`.  Put the following code in it:

```
Around('@AndIwillwalk500miles') do |scenario, block|
  500.times { block.call }
end
```

When you're done, remove the tag.  If you want to run just one scenario from your feature, just tag it instead.  This way you can run as many or as few tests as you want 500 times, without needing to use Rake or mess with the command line.  This is especially useful if you are moving between operating system environments.

Comment: it would be even better if the Around hook can take regex and parse the times from the tag! Or if we can get the times from command line.

Answer (score 3):

This can also be accomplished using a Scenario Outline and nested steps:

Create a Scenario Outline with N Examples. The scenario will run N times.

```
Feature: Login Robustness

  Scenario Outline: I want to be assured that login works consistently
    When i run login # "<login>" repeatedly, it never fails

  Examples:
    | login                |
    | repeated login # 1   |
    | repeated login # 2   |
    | repeated login # N   | 
           …
```

Utilize your existing steps as nested steps within the scenario outline you define:

```
When(/^i run login \# "(.*?)" repeatedly, it never fails$/) do |login_run_number|
  puts login_run_number
  steps %{
  Given I am at initial login, Core
  When A correct username and password are entered, Native (Core)
  Then I should be logged in, Native (Core)
}
end
```

**Advantages:**

- Only one report is written for the entire test run; there are not N
  reports to dig through to see the results.
- It uses existing cucumber functionality; no modifications to the
  framework are needed.
- Testers already understand how Scenario Outlines work.

**Disadvantages:**

- Ugly, multiline .feature file.

Comment: No need for an additional step definition, just change "Screnario" to "Scenario Outline" and add "Examples:" to the bottom of it with N different values and a name of your choosing.

Answer (score -2):

This is a silly work around, but try this

cucumber features/file.feature features/../features/file.feature

as long as the path to file is not identical each time, you can tack on as many ".." as you want